# Ranger's default filetype association

Tags: linux, mime-types

I want to make [`ranger`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ranger) open GIFs in `mpv` instead of in `feh`.

I added the line `image/gif=mpv.desktop;` in `~/.config/mimeapps.list` (under `[Default Applications]`), updated the database with `update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime/`. Now `xdg-mime query default image/gif` outputs `mpv.desktop`.

I tried opening .gif file in PCManFM and it opens up in `mpv`, but `ranger` still opens .gif files in `feh`.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ranger holds it's file associations in `~/.config/ranger/rifle.conf`, so adding filetype gif and associating it with mpv should do the job.

Just add this line to `~/.config/ranger/rifle.conf`:
`^mime image/gif, has mpv,     X, flag f = mpv -- "$@"`.